# Screen scraping using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some information from a website. I need to click on a link which is inside the 'a' tag. I am able to get to the tag. But when I try to click on it. I am getting a error called 'NoneType' object is not callable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("url")
browser.find_element_by_class_name('formButton').click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')

embargo = soup.find_all(class_="dataOff")

for row in embargo:
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    rail = cells[0].get_text().strip()
    embargo = cells[1].find_element_by_class_name('dataOff').click()
```

Here is the HTML tag I want the beautiful soup to click on.

```
<table class="dataLiquidTable">
<tr id = "headerRow> .... </tr>
<tr class = "dataOff">
<td> AO </td>
<td> <a href="url"> </a> </td>
```

The code should click the link which is inside the 'a' tag.

Comment: It won't help that the HTML is broken with `"headerRow`. Also, it looks like you are trying to find "dataOff" within "dataOff". This will fail according to your fragment, "dataOff" is only on the row.

Comment: The header row contains the heading of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following which targets the first child `a` tag with element with class `dataOff` in the table

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".dataLiquidTable .dataOff a").click()
```

Looks like perhaps you want multiple links in which case try and extract links first (hopefully they are valid Urls)

```
links = [item.get_attribute('href') for item in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".dataLiquidTable .dataOff a")]
for link in links:
    browser.get(link)
```

You would then join the info you get from those pages with the info from the start of your code. Assuming lengths of returned lists are the same.

I am not sure

```
embargo = cells[1].find_element_by_class_name('dataOff').click()
```

is valid as it is performing an action yet you attempt an assignment. I assume you want to go to a new page. If you can clarify that. That step is what I am replacing by gathering the links from the a tag elements to use as required.

Otherwise, you can always gather the webElements with

```
elems = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".dataLiquidTable .dataOff a")
```

Comment: erm... what is your question please?

Comment: <td> <a href="url"> sample text </a> </td>  . I want the code to click on this. e.g Click on the sample text which will take me to the new page. Also embargo = cells[1].find_element_by_class_name('dataOff').click() is not working with an error called 'NoneType' object is not callable.

Comment: Then  see my section where i extract all the links into a list you can try to .get to

Comment: How can I click on the first link stored in the list?

Comment: see my syntax. You don't click. You pass the url to browser.get(link)

Comment: If the browser does not click on the first link, then I won't know if I am on the page where I want to extract information from. If the browser clicks on the first page, then it would take me to the page I want to extract information from.

Comment: Just use my first line then: browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".dataLiquidTable .dataOff a").click()

Comment: I am getting a error when I run your first line. NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element